# select/choose this teacher's class

Tags: word-choice

Many English learners use **select** in this context,

> Students **select** this teacher's class because he is so humorous.

To me, **select** means the action of selecting a teacher in a form on the school's website. However, I feel in most cases people are not talking about that action. I think it's better to use **choose** or **sign up for** in this context.

Am I right?

Comment: Not really. "Select" and "choose" can be synonyms in some contexts like this. I don't see an issue with either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is incorrect. **Select** was [used as a verb](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=select_VERB&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) long before computers existed, let alone GUIs. It's possible that young people now associate it primarily with computers, but I have no insights into that. Certainly all native speakers regardless of age understand that it can describe the action of choosing one class from a list of several.

**Select** is of [Latin origin](https://www.etymonline.com/word/select). **Choose** is of [Germanic origin](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=choose). English often contains options of different origin, and you have discovered a pair.

**Sign up** also fits this context because enrolling in a class will create a *textual record*. But **signing up** does not require that a choice be made between two classes. You might easily **sign up** for a class when it is the only class available.

Overall, any of the three would sound natural regarding enrollment in a class. **Select** sounds a little more formal to my ears, as is often the case with words of Latin origin. But that might not be true for everyone.